# Editar corpo email php com html

Tags: php, html, email

Necessitava de editar o corpo de um email (depois de preenchido o formulário, é enviado um email). Mas não estou a conseguir integrar o meu código HTML com o PHP.

Vou enviar um printscreen do que está a acontecer.[image: corpo de email a formatar]

O que pretendia era algo como isto - https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/csstricks-uploads/before-and-after.png

CÓDIGO:

```
<?php
// Sanitize data, or initialize if they don't exist.
$clientname = isset( $_POST['ci_name'] ) ? esc_html( trim( $_POST['ci_name'] ) ) : '';
$email      = isset( $_POST['ci_email'] ) ? esc_html( trim( $_POST['ci_email'] ) ) : '';
$arrive     = isset( $_POST['arrive'] ) ? esc_html( trim( $_POST['arrive'] ) ) : '';
$depart     = isset( $_POST['depart'] ) ? esc_html( trim( $_POST['depart'] ) ) : '';
$guests     = isset( $_POST['adults'] ) ? intval( $_POST['adults'] ) : '0';
$children   = isset( $_POST['children'] ) ? intval( $_POST['children'] ) : '0';
$message    = isset( $_POST['ci_comments'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( stripslashes( $_POST['ci_comments'] ) ) : '';
$timeguest     = isset( $_POST['ci_timeguest'] ) ? esc_html(trim($_POST['ci_timeguest'])) : '';
$contactguest     = isset( $_POST['ci_contactguest'] ) ? esc_html(trim($_POST['ci_contactguest'])) : '';
$autorizo = isset( $_POST['autorizo'] ) ? 'Autorizo o uso do email.' : 'Não autorizo o uso do email.';
$camaextra = isset( $_POST['camaextra'] ) ? 'Necessito de uma cama extra.' : 'Não necessito de uma cama extra.';


// Message is optional, so, no check.

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Alright, lets send the email already!
if ( empty( $errorString ) ) {

$mailbody .= '<html><body>';
$mailbody .= '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/email.jpg" />';
$mailbody .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';

        $mailbody .= __('Nome:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $clientname . "\n";
        $mailbody .= __('Email:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $email . "\n";
        $mailbody .= __('Chegada:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $arrive . "\n";
        $mailbody .= __('Saída:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $depart . "\n";
        $mailbody .= __('Adultos:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $guests . "\n";
        $mailbody .= __('Crianças:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $children . "\n";
        $mailbody .= __('Quarto:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $room->post_title . "\n";
        $mailbody .= __('Mensagem:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $message . "\n";
        $mailbody .= __('Hora do Check-in (hh:mm):', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $timeguest . "\n";
        $mailbody .= __('Contacto:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $contactguest . "\n";
        $mailbody .= __('Autorização:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $autorizo . "\n";
        $mailbody .= __('Cama Extra:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $camaextra . "\n";
        $mailbody .= "</table>";
        $mailbody .= "</body></html>";


        mail($to, $mailbody, $headers); 

        // If you want to receive the email using the address of the sender, comment the next $emailSent = ... line
        // and uncomment the one after it.
        // Keep in mind the following comment from the wp_mail() function source:
        /* If we don't have an email from the input headers default to wordpress@$sitename
        * Some hosts will block outgoing mail from this address if it doesn't exist but
        * there's no easy alternative. Defaulting to admin_email might appear to be another
        * option but some hosts may refuse to relay mail from an unknown domain. See
        * http://trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5007.
        */
        //$emailSent = wp_mail(ci_setting('booking_form_email'), get_option('blogname').' - '. __('Booking form', 'ci_theme'), $mailbody);
     $emailSent = wp_mail(ci_setting('booking_form_email'), get_option('blogname').' - '. __('Formulário de Reserva','theme-text-domain', 'ci_theme'), $mailbody, 'From: "'.$clientname.'" <'.$email.'>');
         $emailSent2 = wp_mail( $email, __('Booking Inquiry','theme-text-domain', 'ci_theme'), __('Thank you so much for your interest in Hotel Aveiro Center! We will get back to you within 24 hours to answer your request.','theme-text-domain','ci_theme'),'From: Hotel Aveiro Center <ricardo.rodrigues@invisual.pt>');


    }


}
?>
```

---

Estou a colocar bem o código?

```
/ To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

            // Alright, lets send the email already!
            if ( empty( $errorString ) ) {

            $mailbody .= '<html><body>';
    $mailbody .= '<img src="http://invisual.pt/hotelaveirocenter/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/email.jpg'. $_SERVER['invisual.pt'] . 'http://invisual.pt/hotelaveirocenter/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/email.jpg" />';
    $mailbody .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';

                $mailbody = __('Nome:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $clientname . "\n";
                $mailbody .= __('Email:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $email . "\n";
                $mailbody .= __('Chegada:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $arrive . "\n";
                $mailbody .= __('Saída:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $depart . "\n";
                $mailbody .= __('Adultos:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $guests . "\n";
                $mailbody .= __('Crianças:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $children . "\n";
                $mailbody .= __('Quarto:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $room->post_title . "\n";
                $mailbody .= __('Mensagem:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $message . "\n";
                $mailbody .= __('Hora do Check-in (hh:mm):', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $timeguest . "\n";
                $mailbody .= __('Contacto:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $contactguest . "\n";
                $mailbody .= __('Autorização:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $autorizo . "\n";
                $mailbody .= __('Cama Extra:', 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $camaextra . "\n";
                $mailbody .= "</table>";
                $mailbody .= "</body></html>";


    mail(
        $to,
        $mailbody,
        $headers
    ); 

    // NOVO header adicionado no wp_mail
    $headersWp  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headersWp .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headersWp .= "From: $clientname" . "\r\n";

     $emailSent = wp_mail(
        ci_setting('booking_form_email'),
        get_option('blogname').' - '. __('Formulário de Reserva','theme-text-domain','ci_theme'),
        $mailbody,
        $headersWp);          


        $emailSent2 = wp_mail(
        $email,
        __('Booking Inquiry','theme-text-domain','ci_theme'),
        __('Thank you so much for your interest in Hotel Aveiro Center! We will get back to you within 24 hours to answer your request.','theme-text-domain','ci_theme'),
        'From: Hotel Aveiro Center <ricardo.rodrigues@invisual.pt>');


            }


        }
```

---

Consegui remover  - WordPress  - . ficando somente o Nome do remetente.

alterando o código

```
$headersWp .= "From: $clientname" . "\r\n";
```

para:

```
$headersWp .= "From: $clientname, <$email>" . "\r\n";
```

Só fica mesmo a faltar a questão dos caracteres com acentos e cedilhas

Comment: Tudo bem meu amigo? Nós do SOpt obviamente queremos te ajudar, mas da maneira que você descreveu dificulta um pouco. Edite sua questão e procure detalhar melhor o que você está tentando, quais erros são retornados, como deveria funcionar e o que você está obtendo, mas não algo como: "pode me ajudar a solucionar/fazer isso", sem que saibamos o que é "isso". 

Quanto mais detalhes melhor. Desde já agradecemos.

Comment: Boa tarde, Obrigado pelas dicas. Sou novo nisto. O que queria basicamente era editar o corpo do email enviado depois de preenchido o formulário no site. Já coloquei esse código acima demonstrado, mas não estou a conseguir o pretendido.

Comment: Só uma pergunta antes que eu poste minha resposta: o printscreen é relativo ao que você está recebendo no seu e-mail? Está usando o que? Gmail? Yahoo? Algum e-mail próprio?

Comment: Sim o printscreen é relativo ao que estou a receber no meu email. Estou a usar um email próprio. (ricardo.rodrigues@dominio.pt) E estou a utilizar o roudcube webmail para ler os emails

Answer (score 1):

Vamos validar os erros antes de prosseguir com a possível solução:

#### 1 - Caminhos (endereços/urls) absolutos

```
$mailbody .= '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/email.jpg" />';
```

O primeiro problema é relativo ao endereço da imagem que você colocou no e-mail. Neste caso o endereço está relativo a sua página e não ao servidor onde ela realmente se encontra.

Basta pensar da seguinte forma: um usuário do gmail, se digitar `/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/email.jpg` após o endereço `https://www.gmail.com` vai conseguir carregar sua imagem? Não, certo? Então o caminho deve ser relativo ao seu servidor, por exemplo:

```
http://www.seusite.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/email.jpg
```

No PHP você pode fazer assim:

```
$mailbody .= '<img src="http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/email.jpg" />';
```

*Obs.: ainda há fatores a serem validados nesta url/domínio, como por exemplo, se é https ou não.*

#### 2 - Mail functions

Notei que você está enviando aparentemente 3 e-mails, porém somente no primeiro você está utilizando os `$headers` e nos demails não.

Lembre de setar o `$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";`, por exemplo:

```
// O trecho abaixo se manteve igual da sua pergunta
mail(
    $to,
    $mailbody,
    $headers
); 

// NOVO header adicionado no wp_mail
$headersWp  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headersWp .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headersWp .= "From: $clientname" . "\r\n";

 $emailSent = wp_mail(
    ci_setting('booking_form_email'),
    get_option('blogname').' - '. __('Formulário de Reserva','theme-text-domain','ci_theme'),
    $mailbody,
    $headersWp);

// O trecho abaixo se manteve igual da sua pergunta
 $emailSent2 = wp_mail(
    $email,
    __('Booking Inquiry','theme-text-domain','ci_theme'),
    __('Thank you so much for your interest in Hotel Aveiro Center! We will get back to you within 24 hours to answer your request.','theme-text-domain','ci_theme'),
    'From: Hotel Aveiro Center <ricardo.rodrigues@invisual.pt>');
```

#### 3 - Código HTML

Baseado no tutorial que você disse que seguiu, creio que você esqueceu de colocar as linhas e colunas (`tr`, `td`).

Sendo assim, segue o código abaixo:

```
$mailbody .= '<html><body>';
    $mailbody .= '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/email.jpg" />';
    $mailbody .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
        $mailbody .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Nome:</strong> </td><td>" . $clientname . "</td></tr>";
        $mailbody .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . $email . "</td></tr>";
        $mailbody .= "<tr><td><strong>Chegada:</strong> </td><td>" .  . $arrive . "</td></tr>";
        $mailbody .= "<tr><td><strong>Saída:</strong> </td><td>" . $depart . "</td></tr>";
        $mailbody .= "<tr><td><strong>Adultos:</strong> </td><td>" . $guests . "</td></tr>";
        $mailbody .= "<tr><td><strong>Crianças:</strong> </td><td>" . $children . "</td></tr>";
        $mailbody .= "<tr><td><strong>Quarto:</strong> </td><td>" . $room->post_title . "</td></tr>";
        $mailbody .= "<tr><td><strong>Mensagem:</strong> </td><td>" . $message . "</td></tr>";
        $mailbody .= "<tr><td><strong>Hora:</strong> </td><td>", 'ci_theme' ) . ' ' . $timeguest . "</td></tr>";
        $mailbody .= "<tr><td><strong>Contacto:</strong> </td><td>" . $contactguest . "</td></tr>";
        $mailbody .= "<tr><td><strong>Autorização:</strong> </td><td>" . $autorizo . "</td></tr>";
        $mailbody .= "<tr><td><strong>Cama:</strong> </td><td>" . $camaextra . "</td></tr>";
    $mailbody .= "</table>";
$mailbody .= "</body></html>";
```

---

Creio que isso irá resolver o seu problema, neste caso, **a falta do header com o Content-type text/html**.

Espero ter ajudado.

Qualquer dúvida deixe um comentário abaixo.

Comment: Não esta a funcionar :( esta a acontecer isto http://i.imgur.com/l3W0B3k.png?1

Comment: Editei minha questão, porém o problema foi que você não seguiu a risca o tutorial. Você criou uma tabela e não colocou linhas nem colunas. Quando for fazer algo do tipo, procure sempre se atentar no que está sendo feito de ambos os lados, pois foi meramente falta de atenção.

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar. só mais uma coisa. Está correcto?:    `código` $mailbody .= '<img src="http://invisual.pt/hotelaveirocenter/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/email.jpg'. $_SERVER['invisual.pt'] . 'http://invisual.pt/hotelaveirocenter/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/email.jpg" />';

Comment: Perfeito @PatrickMaciel. Muito obrigado. Está a funcionar. Neste momento só me acontece um problema com o texto. Palavras com acentos e "Ç" não aparecem direito. e no remetente do email aparece " WordPress <Ricardo Barbosa>"  dá para retirar o "Wordpress". Muito obrigado

Comment: @RicardoRafaelRodrigues Basta alterar o charset no header para `utf-8`. Editei a resposta.